# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getNFTNames is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am not so familiar with javascript, and i'm using someone else's code, and added some new functions with parameters, and it's throwing the following error

It's somehow not recognizing the functions with parameters.

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getNFTNames is not defined
```

```
window.App = {
 start: function() {
  var self = this;

  Voting.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  NFTContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
  self.populateNFTs();
 },

populateNFTs: function() {
  var self = this;
  NFTContract.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
    contractInstance.allNFTs.call().then(function(NFTArray) {
      for(let i=0; i < NFTArray.length; i++) {
        NFTs[NFTArray[i]] = "tokenID-" + i;
      }
      console.log("NFT Array = " + JSON.stringify(NFTs));
      self.setupNFTRows();
    })
  })
 },

 setupNFTRows: function() {
  Object.keys(NFTs).forEach(function (NFTid) { 
    $("#NFT-rows").append(
      `<tr id='NFT_ID_${NFTid}'>
          <td>NFT_ID_${NFTid}</td>
          <td>${this.getNFTNames(NFTid)}</td> 
//changed from self => this. Error thrown: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getNFTNames is not defined
          <td>${this.getCreators(NFTid)}</td>
         </tr>`);
  });
},

getNFTNames:function (nftid){
  NFTContract.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
    contractInstance.getNFTname.call(nftid).then(function(v) {
      return v.toString();
    });
  });
}

}
```

Comment: use `this` not `self` - `self` points to the global object, also you havent declared it in your `setupNFTRows` function

Comment: @skara9, thank you for your comment. I used ```this``` instead of ```self```, but still getting the same error, ```app.js:22265 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getNFTNames is not defined```

Comment: can you update the code in your question and find the exact line the error is on?

Comment: @skara9, yeap, I've updated the code to the current version

Comment: and adding `var self = this` gives the same error? which line is it on exactly

Comment: @skara9, I added a comment to the line of the code, that's causing an error. 
I've changed ```self.getNFTNames(NFTid)``` to ```this.getNFTNames(NFTid)```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? What is `NFTContract`? What code have you copied and from where?

Answer (score 1):

In the `#setupNFTRows` method you tried to call the `#getNFTNames` function on the `self` variable but the `self` variable wasnt yet defined in that function scope, only the one prior. Add the reference in the `#setupNFTRows` method.

```js
 setupNFTRows: function() {
  var self = this;
  Object.keys(NFTs).forEach(function (NFTid) { 
    $("#NFT-rows").append(
      `<tr id='NFT_ID_${NFTid}'>
          <td>NFT_ID_${NFTid}</td>
          <td>${self.getNFTNames(NFTid)}</td>
          <td>${self.getCreators(NFTid)}</td>
         </tr>`);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I did exactly as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error like this: ```Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: getNFTNames is not defined```

Somehow, the function is not recognized...